# Regular expression capturing more than expected

Tags: c#, regex

New dad, so my eyes are tired and I'm trying to figure out why this code:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(https:)?\/");
Console.WriteLine (regex.Replace("https://foo.com", ""));
```

Emits:

> foo.com

I only have the one forward slash, so why are both being captured in the group for the replacement?

Comment: Congrats on entering the domain of fatherhood! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In a specified input string, replaces all strings that match a regular expression pattern with a specified replacement string.

Every single `/` matches the regular expression pattern `@"(https:)?\/"`. If you try e.g. `"https://foo/./com/"`, all `/`s would be removed.

Comment: Criminy - because `https` is optional, all slashes will always be matched.

Comment: @MisterEpic I suggest using var regex = new Regex(@"(https?:(\/){2})?");

Answer (score 3):

If you check what matches are generated, it becomes clear. Add this to your code:

```
var matches = regex.Matches("https://foo.com");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

And you'll see that `https:/` is matched and replaced, `/` is matched and replaced (because `https:`is optional) and `foo.com` remains.